# SyntaxError: unterminated string literal in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

In my worpress I am using a shortcode then I got this error.

Originally the code was written like this:

```
...
var htmlAppendString='<div class="slider_page_info"><div class="val">1</div><div class="arrow"></div></div>';
            jQuery( '.wpp_pagination_slider .ui-slider-handle', this ).append(htmlAppendString);
...
```

when I inspect the element of the page content, the js code became like this.

```
...
var htmlAppendString='
<div class="slider_page_info">
<div class="val">1</div>
<div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
<p>';jQuery('.wpp_pagination_slider .ui-slider-handle',this).append(htmlAppendString);
...
```

Does anyone have an idea about this?
any help will be appreciated..

## Edited,

I Tried the code to be look like this:

```
var htmlAppendString= "\<div class='slider_page_info'>\<div class='val'>1</div>\<div class='arrow'></div>\</div>";
            jQuery( '.wpp_pagination_slider .ui-slider-handle', this ).append(htmlAppendString));
```

but when I run the page and inspect the element, the script will look like this:

```
....
var htmlAppendString="\
<div class='slider_page_info'>\
<div class='val'>1</div>
<p>\
<div class='arrow'></div>
<p>\</p></div>
<p>";jQuery('.wpp_pagination_slider .ui-slider-handle',this).append(htmlAppendString));
....
```

Does it caused by the js minify or jquery conflict?

Comment: use appendTo instead of append

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this,

```
...
var htmlAppendString=
'<div class="slider_page_info">'+
'<div class="val">1</div>'+
'<div class="arrow"></div>'+
'</div>'+
'<p>';
jQuery('.wpp_pagination_slider .ui-slider-handle',this).append(htmlAppendString);
...
```

or You can escape the literal newline,

```
...
var htmlAppendString=
'<div class="slider_page_info">\
<div class="val">1</div>\
<div class="arrow"></div>\
</div>\
<p>';jQuery('.wpp_pagination_slider .ui-slider-handle',this).append(htmlAppendString);
...
```

If you want align the code with the first method then use `\n` for new line

```
...
var htmlAppendString=
'<div class="slider_page_info">\n'+
'<div class="val">1</div>\n'+
'<div class="arrow"></div>\n'+
'</div>\n'+
'<p>';
jQuery('.wpp_pagination_slider .ui-slider-handle',this).append(htmlAppendString);
...
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but whenever I tried to edit the js script, when it runs in the wordpress page i got the same error and when I inspect the element of the source, the code became like this `var htmlAppendString='` same from what I have paste above